# Cypress/Rails cookie issue preventing user staying signed in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, cypress

I'm running into an issue which I can't determine the cause off. I have defined the following commands within Cypress:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('createUser', (opts, permissions = []) => {
  railsRequest('create_user', { user: opts, permissions })
    .its('body')
    .its('response');
});

Cypress.Commands.add('create', (type, opts) => {
  railsRequest('create', { type, opts })
    .its('body')
    .its('response');
});

Cypress.Commands.add('login', { prevSubject: true }, (subject) => {
  railsRequest('login', { id: subject.id })
    .its('body')
    .its('response')
    .as('currentUser');
});
```

The `createUser` command is fairly self explanatory, the `create` command allows me to create dummy data on the server and the `login` command logs the previously created user in to the server setting the session cookie.

I've got the following spec (which currently has no assertions as I'm playing around) which I'm having issues with:

```
describe('My Spec', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.createUser({}, ['permission_name'])
      .login();
  });

  it('testing', function() {
    cy.visit('/');
    cy.create('other_resource', { name: 'resource name' }, company_id: this.currentUser.company_id)
      .as('resource')
      .then(resource => {
        cy.visit('/resource');
      });
  });
});
```

Nothing particularly complicated, but here is what's going on:

- User is created
- Login takes place
- visits '/' which works properly. Chrome shows the page loading as expected
- New 'resource' is created
- When ready, visits '/resources' - here however the app redirects to the login page. Seemingly the user has been logged out.

What I don't get is why the user is being logged out. I added in the cookie debugging and see the session cookie being changed on each request so it seems like the session cookie is OK, but something clearly isn't working correctly.

We have no issues with the app itself when running so I don't THINK it's the back end but if someone has any idea of what's going on I'd love some insight

Comment: I don't know much about Rails, but perhaps you never get logged in? Reason is, `Cypress.Commands.add('createUser'...` should return something for the chained `.login()` to receive. Try `console log(subject)` in login to see if you are getting a parameter passed in.

Comment: It seems like it is being logged in just fine though - the first `cy.visit('/')` after the login shows the user being taken to the dashboard which isn't possible without being logged in. I'll double check though

Comment: You should check the chaining as I suggested, something does not add up here. Perhaps it's just the code shown in the question is not exact?

Comment: Just had a quick check and put a console log in the `login` command outputting the `subject` and it's definitely a JSON object of the user that was returned in the request so it's getting through alright. I can only assume there's some sorta of issue with the cookie being out of sync with cyress' requests as the cookie seems to be changing on each request

Comment: Please provide us with a working GitHub repository so we can debug it directly, we're blind at the moment expect for your issue description 

Comment: hm that's gonna take quite a long time I think, lots of parts. Will keep trying and do that if I can't get anywhere :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so it was me being an idiot in the cypress controller in rails. I've got a controller responsible for the calls to create data and handle any ruby code, but on the `create` call it was setting up the test suite for the helpers that it uses, but the method that was responsible for that was also clearing the database. So essentially, the user was being logged in, then when it asked the server to create the dummy data it wiped the database (including the new user) and then tried to continued.

Needless to say any future request resulted in being redirected to the login page because the user didn't exist